# Rails - invalid authenticity token error for cached form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a Rails app (version 4.2.5) that uses the rack-offline gem to cache a form that users can fill out when they have no internet connection (entries are stored as localStorage objects which can be submitted later when user has connectivity).  However, when the form is submitted, I am getting the error

`ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken in EntriesController#create`

This occurs when I open a new browser window while the Rails server is off and navigate to http://localhost:3000/entries/new (the page has been cached - it renders just fine), fill out the form, then turn the server back on and try to submit.

From my Entries controller:

```
def create
    @entry = Entry.create(entry_params)
    redirect_to "http://localhost:3000/entries"
end
```

And the Application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    protect_from_forgery with: :exception
end
```

And the  in my layout view includes `<%= csrf_meta_tags %>`

Are there any ways that I can get around this issue without compromising the security of the app?

EDIT
In the Application controller, I replaced

```
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
```

with

```
protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
```

and this solved the problem.  However, I don't know enough about what all of this means to understand whether or not this creates a security vulnerability.  Does it?  (PS - I really want to avoid security vulnerabilities)

Answer (score 2):

The csrf_meta_tags are useful for ajax form submissions if you have javascript that's smart enough to use them. Otherwise you need to put a regular form field with the token into your form:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :authenticity_token, form_authenticity_token %>
```

This will likely fix your issue if you are in the case where you have somehow built a form without including the authenticity token.

Here are some other ideas:

1. check to make sure the authenticity token is actually being sent to the server by inspecting the HTTP exchange
2. ensure the server that served your form is the same as the one that's receiving the form submission (or at least that the secret_key_base matches between the servers)
3. ensure the session cookie you used to retrieve the form isn't missing or expired when you submit the form
4. speaking of cookies, make sure the session cookie you send is exactly the same one as the one you retrieved when you requested the form. I've seen this happen when you have multiple cookies with the same name with multiple different domain fields set. You can start by clearing them all to see what you end up with by the end.

Comment: Thanks - I tried this out, but that gave me the error `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken`.  I also tried <%= hidden_field_tag "authenticity_token", form_authenticity_token %> which I'd seen someone recommend elsewhere  - same results.  What might I be overlooking?

Comment: I added just about everything else I can think of where I've seen this go wrong.

Comment: Thank you - I'll work with this and see what I can come up with.

Comment: Ah - I think that I understand the problem... the form itself is being served in the Javascript for the page (it is created dynamically), then cached via rack::offline.  Then I'm shutting down the server and restarting it, meaning that I'm violating your second point above.  I'll see if I can figure out a way around this - it makes me think that I might need to structure my app a little differently...